# How to save {UINT16, 2} array to image in Julia

Tags: image, julia, hdf5, image-size, ijulia-notebook

I have an Array{UInt16,2} in Julia of size 5328×3040. I want to save it to a png image.

I tried the following:

```
save("gray.png", colorview(Gray, img))
```

But got the following error:

```
ERROR: TypeError: in Gray, in T, expected T<:Union{Bool, AbstractFloat, FixedPoint}, got Type{UInt16}
Stacktrace:
 [1] ccolor_number at C:\Users\ankushar\.julia\packages\ImageCore\KbJyT\src\convert_reinterpret.jl:60 [inlined]
 [2] ccolor_number at C:\Users\ankushar\.julia\packages\ImageCore\KbJyT\src\convert_reinterpret.jl:57 [inlined]
 [3] colorview(::Type{Gray}, ::Array{UInt16,2}) at C:\Users\ankushar\.julia\packages\ImageCore\KbJyT\src\colorchannels.jl:104
 [4] top-level scope at REPL[16]:1
caused by [exception 3]
IOError: symlink: operation not permitted (EPERM)
```

I am using Julia 1.4.2

Can you suggest a good way to store these arrays as images in Julia?

TIA!

Comment: shouldn't your values be between 0 and 1.0?

Comment: You are suggesting to normalize the values to 1.0? And change it to float type?

Comment: How about ```img = rand(UInt16, 100, 200);  colorview(Gray, img ./ maximum(img))``` ?

Comment: @daycaster, thank you for your pointer. It worked for me. I used the same formula you have mentioned. Turns out it had to be normalized to 1.0 in order to convert to the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can normalize the pixel values before saving.

```
using Images

img = rand(UInt16, 10, 20)

img[1:3]

# => 3-element Array{UInt16,1}:
 0x7fc2
 0x057e
 0xae79

gimg = colorview(Gray, img ./ typemax(UInt16))

gimg[1:3] |> channelview

# => 3-element reinterpret(Float64, ::Array{Gray{Float64},1}):
 0.4990615701533532
 0.02145418478675517
 0.6815442130159457

save("gray.png", gimg)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A faster and more accurate solution is to reinterpret your array as an array of `N0f16` which is a type from `FixedPointNumbers` which is basically just a `Uint16` scaled between `0` and `1`. This will both avoid rounding errors, but also prevent the need for making a copy.

```
using FixedPointNumbers

img = rand(UInt16, 10, 20)
colorview(Gray, reinterpret(N0f16, img)))
```

Comment: I tried using the reinterpret function here to change Unit16 to N0f16, but this led to a blank image when I saved it. Although dividing it by max value saved the image I expected. What could be going wrong here?